# Nested List Comprehension clearing one list during iteration

Tags: python, list-comprehension

How do you convert the code below into a List Comprehension? I'm confused about how to clear one of the lists during the iteration. I've seen how to do it before but I don't remember what it's called. Let alone what you call clearing a list during iteration (if there's a name for it).

```
data = [{"meal":"tacos","numbers":["0","1","2","3","4","5"]},{"meal":"pizza","numbers":["0","1","2","3","4","5"]}]

node_01 = []
for i in data:
    node_02 = []
    for x in i["numbers"]:
        node_02.append({"meal":i["meal"], "number":x})
    node_01.append({"master_list":"ML", "new_data":node_02})
```

Output:

```
[{'master_list': 'ML',
  'new_data': [{'meal': 'tacos', 'number': '0'},
   {'meal': 'tacos', 'number': '1'},
   {'meal': 'tacos', 'number': '2'},
   {'meal': 'tacos', 'number': '3'},
   {'meal': 'tacos', 'number': '4'},
   {'meal': 'tacos', 'number': '5'}]},
 {'master_list': 'ML',
  'new_data': [{'meal': 'pizza', 'number': '0'},
   {'meal': 'pizza', 'number': '1'},
   {'meal': 'pizza', 'number': '2'},
   {'meal': 'pizza', 'number': '3'},
   {'meal': 'pizza', 'number': '4'},
   {'meal': 'pizza', 'number': '5'}]}]
```

Comment: What do you mean "clearing one of the lists"? Do you mean removing elements from it while you're iterating over it? Aside from the fact that that's normally a bad idea, it's also not what your example code is currently doing.

Comment: Ah, perhaps you mean the fact that `node_2` is reinitialised each iteration, it's like it's being cleared.

Comment: Can you please write an output you want, it would help us understand what exactly do you want.

Comment: Thanks for your interest in my question. node_02 gets cleared every iteration because it's just a temporary list to be appended to node_01. Out of curiosity, why is this a bad idea and could you provide an example of something better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility:

```
data = [{"meal":"tacos","numbers":["0","1","2","3","4","5"]},{"meal":"pizza","numbers":["0","1","2","3","4","5"]}]
result = [{'master_list':'ML', 'new_data':[{"meal":i["meal"], "number":x} for x in i['numbers']]} for i in data]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[  {"meal":i["meal"], "numbers":j } for j in i["numbers"]  for i in data]
```

Explanation: 
To write  a list comprehension start by a loop enclosed in the list

Step1. `[ for i in data]`
This step will produce an iterator to an existing list. Now if you see for every iteration the value of `i["numbers"]` will be a new list.

Step2. `[{"meal":i["meal"], "new_data":i["numbers"]} for i in data]`

Parse the value of i to create a new dictionary out of it. But this is a bit more complex because you have list of numbers. until this step you will get the same data as your original

Step3: `[  {"meal":i["meal"], "numbers":j } for j in i["numbers"]  for i in data]`
Since We know that i["numbers"] itself is a list we can then iterate that list as well and we create a new iterator just for the numbers list

Remember to understand list comprehension start from the right which are iterators and left most thing will be the value that is the final value-added in the list. Whenever you start writing list comprehension start from right.

Hope my explanation helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the output doesn't match the output that I'm looking for. Ajax1234 got it.

Comment: Yes @M4cJunk13 I just gave you the answer how to create a new list using list comprehension. That i believe was the main logic that you asked for.